# Detect collision between multiple UIImageViews that are animated with the same name

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, collision-detection

I am trying to detect the collision between a falling/animated UIImageView that is created every second with an NSTimer. Here's the code:

```
-(void)newobject{

    int randomx = 76+ arc4random() %(290);
    int randomDuration = 2+ arc4random() %(6);
    int randomImage = 1+ arc4random() %(3) ;

    NewObject = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(randomx,0,36 ,36)];        
    UIImage *imag = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ball.png"];
    [NewObject setImage:imag];
    [self.view addSubview:NewObject];

    numberofObjects += 1;
    NewObject.tag = numberofObjects;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:randomDuration];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDone:finished:context:)];
    NewObject.frame = CGRectMake(randomx, 300,NewObject.frame.size.width,NewObject.frame.size.height);

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

That code crates a new UIImageView with the name NewObject and animates it down the screen. To detect the collision I have another NSTimer that is called every 1.0/60. Here's the code:

```
-(void)Collison{

    for (int i = 1; i < numberofObjects; i++) {
        UIImageView *image = NewObject;

        [image viewWithTag:i];
        CALayer *layer = image.layer.presentationLayer;
        CGRect NewObjectFrame =  layer.frame;
        CALayer *layer2 = Sprint.layer.presentationLayer;
        CGRect SprintFrame = layer2.frame;

        if (CGRectIntersectsRect(NewObjectFrame, SprintFrame)) {
            [self StopTimers];

            NSLog(@"hello");
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the console says "It works" but the UIImage didn't collide and I can collide the character with the image but the console says nothing and at the same time if I try to collide the character with the UIImageView it works. What i'am trying to say is that it's not reliable. Can someone help?

update: I edited the code but now it detecting the last uiimageview that is added.

Comment: Is `NewObject` an instance variable? Shouldn't you be keeping track of each NewObject that you have created, e.g. by storing them in an NSMutableArray and iterating over the entire array to find collisions?

Comment: yeah i was thinking of that but the problem is how do i add the NewObject to the NSMutableArray with a different name e.g newObject1,NewObject2..... to identify the object that was collided. to answer your first question yes it is a instance variable.

Comment: How about creating a new class that contains a UIImageView and an NSString? You would then use the NSString to assign a unique identifier to each object.

Comment: can you give me an example with some code?

Comment: You don't need to worry about what your instances are named when adding them to an `NSMutableArray`, as long as the object is in a new memory space then the pointers in the array will point to the appropriate object, it doesn't care about the name you gave it. As far as determining what view you are dealing with, that is exactly what the `tag` property is for on UIView. I see you are using it to some extent but I didn't follow your code completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok well i got it. It's simple so all you need to do is make an NSMutableArray and check the array for collision with a for loop.